# ExcelDna C API calls from asynchronous WPF window running in a different thread than Excel

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, excel-dna, c-api

I have an asynchronous WPF window running over Excel in a separated thread. I'm trying to use C API calls, embedded in ExcelDna.Utilities library to access heavy amounts of data spread over various Excel workbooks/spreadsheets.

Any call I try throws an error, that I'm supposing its because it is running in a different thread and does not access the Excel running thread to get its Application object.

When I try to do the same through a macro (a c# method called by ribbon button ) it works with no problem. That is the first clue to make sure its a thread problem.

I'm a newbie in multi-threading, but as far as I know, I should call it from the Dispatcher object.
The problem is that I can't figure out a way to do that.

Are my suppositions correct, or there is another thing I'm just overlooking?
If so, how to access ''ExcelDna.Utilities.XLApp'' from Dispatcher?

`ExcelDna.Utilities.Workbook[] workbooks = ExcelDna.Utilities.XLApp.Workbooks;`

By the way, Office.Interop works in the window thread, but it is not an option for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can schedule code to run on the main thread, in a macro context where the C API is safe to call, with the Excel-DNA helper `ExcelAsyncUtil.QueueAsMacro`.

Comment: As I said it worked perfectly, but I cannot figure out a way to be notified when the queued macro has been run, so I could call other methods. As I workaround I am just calling it from queued macro just before it ends. Is there a way to register some method to be run after QueueAsMacro has successfully ended?